# Cannot use enumitem-zref

Tags: packages, texlive, enumitem, zref

I have following MWE:

```tex
% -------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem,enumitem-zref}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start=34,label=(\arabic*),name=thelist]
\item stuff
\item more stuff \label{more stuff}
\item yet more
\end{enumerate}

The is \refitem{thelist,35} or \refitem{thelist{35}}
and this is also \refitem{more stuff}


\end{document}\endinput
% -----------------------------------------------------
```

After compiling I have following errors:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\zen@item@comma ->\begingroup \c@zenidx 
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ifcsname Z@R@zen>\the \c@zenidx 
You can't use `\endcsname' after \the.
<argument> ...e Z@R@zen>\the \c@zenidx \endcsname 
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
...
Package zref: Property `zen@anchor,zen@currentlabelname' does not exist.
Package enumitem: name undefined.
```

I have enumitem and enumitem-zref packages installed.
Is this bug?

Comment: unrelated but are you sure you want `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` ? for example all code posted here is in utf-8 not latin1

Comment: The first error is `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \globcount` the errors you show are essentially spurious followon if you scroll past the error

Comment: `enumitem-zref` is falling over changes made in 2015 so I guess it is unmaintained `\let\globcount\newcount` gets past the errors you show but it then triggers errors in `zref`  what is your actual use case here are you sure you need this package?

Comment: `Package zref: Property \`zen@anchor,zen@currentlabelname' does not exist`  is due to a change made in  zref in 2010, zref has the comment `% Between 2010/04/19 v2.13 and 2010/10/22 v2.19 a comma separated list  of properties could be used as argument \meta{propname}.`  ... So `enumitem-zref` worked for 6 months, 12 years ago, but has not worked since.

Comment: As David wrote the package is broken since a long time. How did you find it?

Comment: I found this MWE here: https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.tex/c/3E-GLKXmxrk?pli=1.
Also, I change encoding to utf8 without success

Comment: the MWE is from 2011. At that time the package probably still worked, but now it is broken, so simply drop it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, My use case of enumitem-zref is labeling itemize environment. I use \captionof at now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for good suggestion :)